# XAMPP. Apache cant start. api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: apache, xampp

When I start apache in XAMPP. The program cant start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer.
How I fix it?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the following windows update: [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2999226) (Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows)

> The missing dll api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is installed with a Windows update. To resolve this issue, download and install the Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows from Microsoft. ([Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/error_on_launch.html))

Sidenote: The details page from Microsoft was last updated in Jan 2017. You probably should install all other updates that have been released since then.

Answer (score -1):

If you have problem install files as api-ms-win-crt… I have a solution. I written simple program in C# which install this missing files to you Windows Tested and working :)Link is there: https://mega.nz/#!JzpkzLBA!qlqeHIVrTsJ8s2yOgLp8tQAIUpAji4sSvS6GjetADk4 . You do not install visual studio redist 2015 because you must have Windows 10. And my program fully working on Windows 7 x64 , and Windows 8.1 x64 (All tested) //Sorry for English im from Czech Republic