# does changing an operating system solve the .dll file issues?

Tags: dll

I tried installing Xammp on my pc (windows 8.1) and it says api-ms-....dll is missing. I have tried every solution I've seen online like upgrading my OS, downloading and installing a new visual studio redistributed 2015 but still not working. please would changing the OS solve this problem?

My question is, does changing the OS from maybe windows 8.1 to windows 7 solve this problem? because I have tried most of the online solutions but still having the same issue

Comment: *"it says api-ms-....dll is missing"* - what is the exact dll's name? `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`? Or maybe `api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll`? Or yet another? Apart from that, I feel like this question is not suited for StackOverflow, but rather for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49209515/1392490

Comment: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll this i what is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following windows update: [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2999226) (Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows)

> The missing dll api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is installed with a Windows update. To resolve this issue, download and install the Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows from Microsoft. ([Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/error_on_launch.html))

Sidenote: The details page from Microsoft was last updated in Jan 2017. You probably should install all other updates that have been released since then.

Comment: I've even tried this, still didn't work. My question is, changing the OS solve this problem or not?

Comment: XAMPP works with WIndows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. So there is no need to change the OS